# Making a typing timer in RxJS; Tracking time spent typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rx-java, rxjs, reactive-programming

This question is an extension of my previous question that you can find here:

[How to use RxJS to display a "user is typing" indicator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41520909/how-to-use-rxjs-to-display-a-user-is-typing-indicator/41521028#41521028)

After having successfully been able to track whether or not the user was typing, I needed to be able to use that particular state as a trigger for a clock.

The logic is simple, essentially I want a clock to be run when the user is typing. But when the user stops typing, I need the clock to pause. When the user starts typing again, the clock should continue to accumulate.

I have already been able to get it to work, but it looks like a mess and I need help refactoring it so it isn't a ball of spaghetti. Here is what the code looks like:

```js
/*** Render Functions ***/

const showTyping = () =>
  $('.typing').text('User is typing...');

const showIdle = () =>
  $('.typing').text('');

const updateTimer = (x) =>
  $('.timer').text(x);

/*** Program Logic ***/

const typing$ = Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent($('#input'), 'input')
  .switchMapTo(Rx.Observable
               .never()
               .startWith('TYPING')
               .merge(Rx.Observable.timer(1000).mapTo('IDLE')))
  .do(e => e === 'TYPING' ? showTyping() : showIdle());

const timer$ = Rx.Observable
  .interval(1000)
  .withLatestFrom(typing$)
  .map(x => x[1] === 'TYPING' ? 1 : 0)
  .scan((a, b) => a + b)
  .do(console.log)
  .subscribe(updateTimer)
```

And here is the link to the live JSBin: http://jsbin.com/lazeyov/edit?js,console,output

Perhaps I will walk you through the logic of the code:

1. I first build a stream to capture each typing event.
2. For each of these events, I will use `switchMap` to: (a) fire off the original "TYPING" event so we don't lose it, and (b) fire off an "IDLE" event, 1 second later. You can see that I create these as separate streams and then merge them together. This way, I get a stream that will indicate the "typing state" of the input box.
3. I create a second stream that sends an event every second. Using `withLatestFrom`, I combine this stream with the previous "typing state" stream. Now that they are combined, I can check whether or not the typing state is "IDLE" or "TYPING". If they are typing, I give the event a value of `1`, otherwise a `0`.
4. Now I have a stream of `1`s and `0`s, all I have to do is add them back up with `.scan()` and render it to the DOM.

What is the RxJS way to write this functionality?

### EDIT: Method 1 — Build a stream of change-events

Based on @osln's answer.

```js
/*** Helper Functions ***/

const showTyping = () => $('.typing').text('User is typing...');
const showIdle = () => $('.typing').text('');
const updateTimer = (x) => $('.timer').text(x);
const handleTypingStateChange = state =>
  state === 1 ? showTyping() : showIdle();

/*** Program Logic ***/

const inputEvents$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#input'), 'input').share();

// streams to indicate when user is typing or has become idle
const typing$ = inputEvents$.mapTo(1);
const isIdle$ = inputEvents$.debounceTime(1000).mapTo(0);

// stream to emit "typing state" change-events
const typingState$ = Rx.Observable.merge(typing$, isIdle$)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .share();

// every second, sample from typingState$
// if user is typing, add 1, otherwise 0
const timer$ = Rx.Observable
  .interval(1000)
  .withLatestFrom(typingState$, (tick, typingState) => typingState)
  .scan((a, b) => a + b, 0)

// subscribe to streams
timer$.subscribe(updateTimer);
typingState$.subscribe(handleTypingStateChange);
```

[JSBin Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/yizope/edit?js,console,output)

### EDIT: Method 2 — Using exhaustMap to start counter when user starts typing

Based on Dorus' answer.

```js
/*** Helper Functions ***/

const showTyping = () => $('.typing').text('User is typing...');
const showIdle = () => $('.typing').text('');
const updateTimer = (x) => $('.timer').text(x);

/*** Program Logic ***/

// declare shared streams
const inputEvents$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#input'), 'input').share();
const idle$ = inputEvents$.debounceTime(1000).share();

// intermediate stream for counting until idle
const countUntilIdle$ = Rx.Observable
  .interval(1000)
  .startWith('start counter') // first tick required so we start watching for idle events right away
  .takeUntil(idle$);

// build clock stream
const clock$ = inputEvents$
  .exhaustMap(() => countUntilIdle$)
  .scan((acc) => acc + 1, 0)

/*** Subscribe to Streams ***/
idle$.subscribe(showIdle);
inputEvents$.subscribe(showTyping);
clock$.subscribe(updateTimer);
```

[JSBin Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/lazeyov/edit?js,console,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice a few problems with your code. The gist of it is good, but if you use different operators you can do the same thing even easier.

First you use [`switchMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap), this is a nice operator to start a new stream every time a new input arrives. However, what you really want is to continue the current timer as long as the user is typing. A better operator here would be [`exhaustMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-exhaustMap) because `exhaustMap` will keep the already active timer until it stops. We can then stop the active timer if the user is not typing for 1 second. That is easily done with `.takeUntil(input.debounceTime(1000))`. That would result in the very short query:

```
input.exhaustMap(() => Rx.Observable.timer(1000).takeUntil(input.debounceTime(1000)))
```

To this query, we can hook the display events you want, `showTyping`, `showIdle` etc. We also need to fix the timers `index`, as it will reset every time the user stops typing. This can be done with using the second parameter of project function in [`map`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map), as this is the index of the value in the current stream.

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#input'), 'input')
  .publish(input => input
    .exhaustMap(() => {
        showTyping();
        return Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
          .takeUntil(input.startWith(0).debounceTime(1001))
          .finally(showIdle);
    })
  ).map((_, index) => index + 1) // zero based index, so we add one.
  .subscribe(updateTimer);
```

Notice i used `publish` here, but it is not strictly needed as the source is hot. However recommended because we use `input` twice and now we do not have to think about if it's hot or cold.

[Live demo](http://jsbin.com/moyoqo/2/edit?js,output)

```js
/*** Helper Functions ***/

const showTyping = () =>
  $('.typing').text('User is typing...');

const showIdle = () =>
  $('.typing').text('');

const updateTimer = (x) =>
  $('.timer').text(x);

/*** Program Logic ***/

Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#input'), 'input')
  .publish(input => input
    .exhaustMap(() => {
        showTyping();
        return Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
          .takeUntil(input.startWith(0).debounceTime(1001))
          .finally(showIdle);
    })
  ).map((_, index) => index + 1) // zero based index, so we add one.
  .subscribe(updateTimer);
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <div>Seconds spent typing: <span class="timer">0</span></div>
    <input type="text" id="input">
    <div class="typing"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, I've made an implementation based off of yours. Can you tell me what is wrong with my implementation since it is missing some of the stuff that you are doing: http://jsbin.com/lazeyov/edit?js,console,output

Comment: @adrianmc Oops, i just realised a mistake here. I used `timer` instead of `interval`, that means the timer stops every second. In your example, if you type slowly, and measure the time between counted seconds, you'll notice it'll go up a little slower than real seconds.

Comment: Do you really need the `.startWith(0)` ?

Comment: @olsn yeah, surprisingly you do. Because `input` triggers `exhaustMap` and then `exhaustMap` subscribes to `input` again inside `takeUntil`, the event that triggered `exhaustMap` is now missed by `takeUntil`. I discovered this when i made a code-snipped out of it, if the user presses 1 key only, the counter will keep going without the `.startWith(0)`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to continuously update the UI, I don't think there's any way around using a timer - I might have written the stream a little differently by initiating the timer by change-events - but your current stream seems also okay as it is already:

```
const inputEvents$ = Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent($('#input'), 'input');

const typing$ = Rx.Observable.merge(
  inputEvents$.mapTo('TYPING'),
  inputEvents$.debounceTime(1000).mapTo('IDLE')
)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .do(e => e === 'TYPING' ? showTyping() : showIdle())
  .publishReplay(1)
  .refCount();

const isTyping$ = typing$
  .map(e => e === "TYPING");

const timer$ = isTyping$
  .switchMap(isTyping => isTyping ? Rx.Observable.interval(100) : Rx.Observable.never())
  .scan(totalMs => (totalMs + 100), 0)
  .subscribe(updateTimer);
```

Live [here](http://jsbin.com/jatikebace/1/edit?js,console,output).

---

If you don't need to update the UI and just want to capture the duration of the typing, you could use start- and stop-events and map them to timestamps like this e.g.:

```
const isTyping$ = typing$
  .map(e => e === "TYPING");

const exactTimer$ = isTyping$
  .map(() => +new Date())
  .bufferCount(2)
  .map((times) => times[1] - times[0])
  .do(updateTimer)
  .do(typedTime => console.log("User typed " + typedTime + "ms"))
  .subscribe();
```

Live [here](http://jsbin.com/lubopawuxu/1/edit?js,console,output).

Comment: Thanks for the awesome response. Is there a better way to write: `Rx.Observable
               .never()
               .startWith('TYPING')
               .merge(Rx.Observable.timer(1000).mapTo('IDLE')))`
?
Why aren't these chainable? Why do I have to create two streams?
Why couldn't I have:
`Rx.Observable.startWith('TYPING').timer(1000).mapTo('IDLE')`?

Comment: you can sure write that differently, i didn't thought that was part of your question - i have updated the answer how i would write that

Comment: interesting, why is the `share()` necessary? And also, what exactly does `publishReplay()` and `refCount()` do?

Comment: the share is not required, i just didn't update the bins ;) - the `publishReplay(1).refCount()` is also not mandatory, but it helps in case some subscriber subscribes late, then it will still receive current state and `publish` because it is used at more than one place and we don't need a completely separate stream for each subscription

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sounds like I need to read up more on multicasting!

Comment: Does it add any value to use `share()` on an already hot stream?

Comment: Nope, as I mentioned above it's not required, I removed it - thanks :)

Comment: Yeah i'm a bit torn up between share or not share myself. It's good practice when you reuse streams, but it looks weird on `.fromEvent` that is inherently hot :)

Comment: And on the subject of `share`, the way you use it is not safe at all on cold streams, you subscribe twice but with a small delay between the subscriptions, if the source fires in that time, you miss one event, that might be problematic in some circumstances. That's why i would use `.publish()` with `.connect()` instead of `.refCount()`, or use `.publish(selector)` like i did in my answer.

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something, but I don't see where it would be subscribed twice - sorry, it's late here ;)

Comment: @olsn As `inputEvents$` is used twice, it is subscribed twice. That's why we use `share()`, an operator specialized in multi-casting. However `fromEvent` will also multi-cast so adding `share()` has little value.

Comment: Yes, that i know - i was asking about the refcount vs. connect

Comment: @olsn Oh, misunderstand your question. With `refCount`, you will subscribe as soon as the first subscriber arrives. Perhaps your source used `.startWith(value)`, and this value is emitted right away. The second subscription, arriving tents of a millisecond later, will not receive the startWith value. With `connect()` you would delay the backing subscription the to source and you can safely subscribe twice before you activate the source.

Comment: yes...i know that and its correct..., but where in this answer are two subscriptions?